# tf.data.Dataset: how to get the dataset size (number of elements in an epoch)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Let's say I have defined a dataset in this way:

```
filename_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("{}/*.png".format(dataset))
```

how can I get the number of elements that are inside the dataset (hence, the number of single elements that compose an epoch)?

I know that `tf.data.Dataset` already knows the dimension of the dataset, because the `repeat()` method allows repeating the input pipeline for a specified number of epochs. So it must be a way to get this information.

Comment: Do you need to have this information *before* the first epoch completed, or is it okay to compute it after?

Comment: Before the first epoch completed

Comment: Working as an `iterator`, I don't think a `Dataset` knows the total number of elements before reaching the last one - then it starts repeating over if requested (c.f. source [repeat_dataset_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/repeat_dataset_op.cc#L125))

Comment: Can't you just list the files in `"{}/*.png".format(dataset)` before (say via `glob` or `os.listdir`), get the length of that and then pass the list to a Dataset? Datasets don't have (natively) access to the number of items they contain (knowing that number would require a full pass on the dataset, and you still have the case of unlimited datasets coming from streaming data or generators)

Comment: @GPhilo I could only in this particular case, but I'd like to have a more general solution.

Comment: @user1735003 thank you for you answer, I'm gonna test it soon. Can you please also add the option to get the size after the end of the first epoch?

Comment: @nessuno the thing is, there is no general solution, because Datasets don't know their size. If you have TFRecord datasets, for example, there is no way for you to know *at creation time* how may samples your dataset contains. The only way is to count them as you go, or do a full pass of the dataset before you start training (which, depending on your dataset's size, can be quite slow)

Comment: @GPhilo understood, thank you for the explanation! However the answer of user1735003 perfectly fits my needs

Comment: From what I can see in official `tf` tutorials - they count *files* before creating a dataset, not number of elements in a dataset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tf.data.Dataset.list_files` creates a tensor called `MatchingFiles:0` (with the appropriate prefix if applicable).

You could evaluate

```
tf.shape(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('MatchingFiles:0'))[0]
```

to get the number of files.

Of course, this would work in simple cases only, and in particular if you have only one sample (or a known number of samples) per image.

In more complex situations, e.g. when you do not know the number of samples in each file, you can only observe the number of samples as an epoch ends.

To do this, you can watch the number of epochs that is counted by your `Dataset`. `repeat()` creates a member called `_count`, that counts the number of epochs. By observing it during your iterations, you can spot when it changes and compute your dataset size from there.

This counter may be buried in the hierarchy of `Dataset`s that is created when calling member functions successively, so we have to dig it out like this.

```
d = my_dataset
# RepeatDataset seems not to be exposed -- this is a possible workaround 
RepeatDataset = type(tf.data.Dataset().repeat())
try:
  while not isinstance(d, RepeatDataset):
    d = d._input_dataset
except AttributeError:
  warnings.warn('no epoch counter found')
  epoch_counter = None
else:
  epoch_counter = d._count
```

Note that with this technique, the computation of your dataset size is not exact, because the batch during which `epoch_counter` is incremented typically mixes samples from two successive epochs. So this computation is precise up to your batch length.

Answer (score 50):

`len(list(dataset))` works in eager mode, although that's obviously not a good general solution.

Comment: It defeats the purpose of it being an iterator. Calling list() runs the entire thing in a single shot. It works for smaller amounts of data, but can likely take too many resources for larger datasets.

Comment: @yrekkehs absolutely, that's why it's not a good general solution. But it works.

Comment: @markemus Didn't mean to sound contentious, I was just trying to answer PhonoDots. :)

Comment: @yrekkehs gotcha, and I agree :)

Answer (score 31):

As of TensorFlow (`>=2.3`) one can use:

```
dataset.cardinality().numpy()
```

Note that the `.cardinality()` method was integrated into the main package (before it was in the `experimental` package).

****NOTE**** that when applying the `filter()` operation this operation can return `-2`.

Comment: `train_ds.cardinality().numpy()` is given me `-2`!!!

Comment: It's giving you -2 because you have used .filter() somewhere in your code

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/cardinality

Comment: You can try to see, this works prior to applying filter :D

Comment: `len(dataset)` also works for Tensorflow `>=2.3` (without having to convert to a `list` first). The main difference with calling `dataset.cardinality()` directly seems to be that `len(dataset)` converts the result into a native Python `int`.

Answer (score 23):

Take a look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26966

It doesn't work for TFRecord datasets, but it works fine for other types.

TL;DR:

> num_elements = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset).numpy()

Answer (score 14):

This has worked for me:

```
length_dataset = dataset.reduce(0, lambda x,_: x+1).numpy()
```

It iterates over your dataset and increments the var x, which is returned as the length of the dataset.

Comment: Given how often cardinality has failed for me without obvious filters I would suggest using this response!

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE:**

Use `tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset)` - see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/cardinality).

---

In case of tensorflow datasets you can use `_, info = tfds.load(with_info=True)`. Then you may call `info.splits['train'].num_examples`. But even in this case it doesn't work properly if you define your own split.

So you may either count your files or iterate over the dataset (like described in other answers):

```
num_training_examples = 0
num_validation_examples = 0

for example in training_set:
    num_training_examples += 1

for example in validation_set:
    num_validation_examples += 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a feature like that yet in TF. With TF 2.0 and eager execution however, you could just iterate over the dataset:

```
num_elements = 0
for element in dataset:
    num_elements += 1
```

This is the most storage efficient way I could come up with

This really feels like a feature that should have been added a long time ago. Fingers crossed they add this a length feature in a later version.

Comment: Alternatively, a more concise way to add things up in TF 2.0: `count = dataset.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1)`

Comment: I found you have to call numpy() on count to get the actual value otherwise count is a tensor. i.e: count = dataset.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy()

Answer (score 7):

I saw many methods of getting the number of samples, but actually you can easily do it by in `keras`:

```py
len(dataset) * BATCH_SIZE
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this for TFRecords in TF2:

```
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(dataset_filenames)
ds_size = sum(1 for _ in ds)
```

Answer (score 4):

For early Tensorflow versions (2.1 or higher):

```
sum(dataset.map(lambda x: 1).as_numpy_iterator())
```

That way you don't have to load each object in your dataset to your run memory, instead you put 1's and sum it.

Answer (score 3):

In TF2.0, I do it like

```
for num, _ in enumerate(dataset):
    pass

print(f'Number of elements: {num}')
```

Answer (score 2):

In TensorFlow 2.6.0 (I am not sure if it was possible in earlier versions or no):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#__len__

```
Dataset.__len__()
```

Answer (score 1):

For some datasets like COCO, cardinality function does not return a size. One way to compute size of a dataset fast is to use map reduce, like so:

```
ds.map(lambda x: 1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE).reduce(tf.constant(0), lambda x,_: x+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but for a large dataset stored in TFRecord datasets I used this (TF 1.15)

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('some_path')
# Count 
n = 0
take_n = 200000
for samples in dataset.batch(take_n):
  n += take_n
  print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to find out the number of the training split in the oxford-iiit-pet dataset:

```py
ds, info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet', split='train', shuffle_files=True, as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

print(info.splits['train'].num_examples)
```

Comment: I think your solution is incorrent. The return object, **ds**, is not the same as what **split['train']** represents. You can see what I mean by this: `(train, val), info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet', split=['train[:70%]','train[70%:]'], shuffle_files=True, as_supervised=True)`. The sizes of subdatasets **train** and **val** change as we modify the percentage specified in **split=** argument. However, `info.splits['train'].num_examples` is fixed at 3680.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in tensorflow 2.4.0 with just `len(filename_dataset)`

Comment: Hi, I think you are wrong. `len()` is not applicable to `tf.data.dataset` object. Based on the discussion of this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26966), it's unlikely to have this feature in the near future.

Comment: Hey, I would not describe it as not applicable. I had a dataset of 391 images and it returned exactly that.

Comment: I knew it works in some cases but generally it doesn't work. `len()` is unable to be applied on a Dataset object like this one, for example, `tfds.load('tf_flowers')['train'].repeat()` because the size of it is infinite.

Comment: Using len(tfdataset) raises TypeError: dataset length is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

As in version=2.5.0, you can simply call `print(dataset.cardinality())` to see the length and type of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I am very surprised that this problem does not have an explicit solution, because this was such a simple feature. When I iterate over the dataset through TQDM, I find that TQDM finds the data size. How does this work?

```
for x in tqdm(ds['train']):
  //Something

-> 1%|          | 15643/1281167 [00:16<07:06, 2964.90it/s]v
```

```
t=tqdm(ds['train'])
t.total
-> 1281167
```

Comment: Are you trying to answer the question or are you asking a question?

Comment: @Yatin I found a very fast solution(the second code snippet), but I also want to understand how this works behind the scenes, and how to clean it up.

Comment: The method doesn't work for MapDataset object.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a simpler way in other answers, so I would show an example of when we download images from a folder. The dataset object of `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` has property `file_paths`. So I think a simple way is just `len(datatset.file_paths)`. When tensorflow load dataset from folder, I think, it stores all paths.