# Determine number of records in tf.data.Dataset Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I would like to pass a dataset iterator into a function, but that function needs to know the length of the dataset. In the example below, I could pass `len(datafiles)` into `my_custom_fn()` function, but I'm wondering if I am able to extract the length of the data set from either `iterator`, `batch_x`, or `batch_y` classes so that I do not have to add it as an input.

```
dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(datafiles, record_bytes)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
[batch_x, batch_y] = iterator.get_next()
value = my_custom_fn(batch_x, batch_y)
# lots of other stuff
```

Thanks!

**Edit**: This solution does not work in my case: [tf.data.Dataset: how to get the dataset size (number of elements in a epoch)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737192/tf-data-dataset-how-to-get-the-dataset-size-number-of-elements-in-a-epoch)

After running

```
tf.data.Dataset.list_files('{}/*.dat')
tf.shape(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('MatchingFiles:0')[0])
```

returns

```
<tf.Tensor 'Shape_3:0' shape=(0,) dtype=int32>
```

**I did find a solution that works for me. Add an iterator_scope to my code like:**

```
with tf.name_scope('iter'):
    dataset = tf.data.FixedLengthRecordDataset(datafiles, record_bytes)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    [batch_x, batch_y] = iterator.get_next()
value = my_custom_fn(batch_x, batch_y)
# lots of other stuff
```

Then from inside `my_custom_fn` call:

```
def my_custom_fn(batch_x, batch_y):
    filenames = batch_x.graph.get_operation_by_name(
                  'iter/InputDataSet/filenames').outputs[0]
    n_epoch = sess.run(sess.graph.get_operation_by_name(
                  'iter/Iterator/count').outputs)[0]
    batch_size = sess.run(sess.graph.get_operation_by_name(
                  'iter/Iterator/batch_size').outputs)[0]
    # lots of other stuff
```

Not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to work. Happy to take any advice on this, as it seem a little hacky.

Comment: This solution does not work in my case. I updated my question to reflect the difference and added a solution that did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The length of an `iterator` is unknown until you iterate through it. You could explicitly pass `len(datafiles)` into the function, but if you are insistent upon the data's persistence, you could simply make the function an instance method and store the length of the dataset within the object for which the `my_custom_fn` is a method.

Unfortunately, as an `iterator` it does not store anything, it generates the data dynamically. However, as found in the source code for TensorFlow, there is a 'private' variable `_batch_size` which stores the batch size. You can review the source code here: [TensorFlow source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/92e6c3e4f5c1cabfda1e61547a6a1b268ef95fa5/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L1623).

Comment: But somewhere in the class it stores the names of the datafiles, no? It seems like I should be able to get to them and get their length? On a similar note, is it possible to access the value of the batch size (if it was set via `dataset.batch(1000)`)?

Comment: @John I've updated my answer to address your comment.