# Confusion matrix not making any sense after training a 3 class image classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm a rookie at machine learning so please bear with me.

I have a model that trains images and classifies them in 3 different classes. I'm trying to get the confusion matrix for the test data, but either I don't understand it or it's not making any sense. When the model is done training after 200 epochs it shows that the accuracy is around 65%:

> loss: 1.5386 - accuracy: 0.6583

But then when the confusion matrix is printed like this:

[[23 51 42]

[20 27 25]

[47 69 56]]

Which isn't correct because the "true" results (23, 27 and 56) don't make up for 65% of all the results. If you add up the numbers in the matrix it adds to the amount of test images so I know that part is correct.

I had a tensorflow warning just before printing the confusion matrix that says the following, but I don't really get its meaning:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 13 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset

This is my code:

```
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop, Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

CLASSES = 3

# define cnn model
def define_model():
    # load model
    base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    #add new classifier layers
    x = base_model.output
    x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
    predictions = Dense(CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

    # mark loaded layers as not trainable
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # compile model
    opt = RMSprop(lr=0.0001)
               #momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# plot diagnostic learning curves
def summarize_diagnostics(history):
    # plot loss
    pyplot.subplot(211)
    pyplot.title('Cross Entropy Loss')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], color='blue', label='train')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], color='orange', label='test')
    # plot accuracy
    pyplot.subplot(212)
    pyplot.title('Classification Accuracy')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['accuracy'], color='blue', label='train')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], color='orange', label='test')
    # save plot to file
    filename = sys.argv[0].split('/')[-1]
    pyplot.savefig(filename + '_plot.png')
    pyplot.close()

# run the test harness for evaluating a model
def run_test_harness():
    # define model
    model = define_model()
    # create data generator
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True)
    # specify imagenet mean values for centering
    datagen.mean = [123.68, 116.779, 103.939]
    # prepare iterators
    train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('../datasetMainPruebas3ClasesQuitandoConfusosCV1/train/',
        class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, target_size=(224, 224))
    test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('../datasetMainPruebas3ClasesQuitandoConfusosCV1/test/',
        class_mode='categorical', batch_size=32, target_size=(224, 224))
    # fit model
    history = model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=len(train_it),
        validation_data=test_it, validation_steps=len(test_it), epochs=200, verbose=1)
    # evaluate model
    _, acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_it, steps=len(test_it), verbose=1)
    print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))

    #confusion matrix
    Y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_it, len(test_it) + 1)
    y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
    print('Confusion Matrix')

    cm = confusion_matrix(test_it.classes, y_pred)
    print(cm)

    # learning curves
    summarize_diagnostics(history)

# entry point, run the test harness
run_test_harness()
```

Any help or tip is welcome, thank you

Edit: after checking one of the comments I changed my CM code to the following:

```
    #confusion matrix
    all_y_pred = []
    all_y_true = []

    for i in range(len(test_it)):
        x, y = test_it[i]
        y_pred = model.predict(x)

        all_y_pred.append(y_pred)
        all_y_true.append(y)

    all_y_pred = np.concatenate(all_y_pred, axis=0)
    all_y_true = np.concatenate(all_y_true, axis=0)

    print('Confusion Matrix')

    cm = confusion_matrix(all_y_true, all_y_pred)
    print(cm)
```

And now the error I get says "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets"

Any idea why?

Comment: the error says `step_per_epoch` given is larger than the batches from generator. Not sure what len(dataset) gives. You may want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737192/tf-data-dataset-how-to-get-the-dataset-size-number-of-elements-in-an-epoch

Comment: The problem is that .classes in a generator does not give you the ground truth labels in the same order as predict, you should not use it, I answered this already at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74367878/is-the-classes-method-of-a-imagedatagenorator-sorted/74411647#74411647 Also the +1 in the len for the generator is not necessary and is what triggers the warning.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I applied the changes you say on your related post, and now I get an error saying "Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets". Do you know why? I edited my post with the new code if you could help me, thank you

Comment: the confusion_matrix function expects class indices, and you are giving it class probabilities (so apply argmax to both of them).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Just did that and now it works, thank you!