# How to separate dataset to validate CNN?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Hello im working training to train a CNN with two datasets that I label manually with negative and positive.(80x60 depth images in each matrix)

```
# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 80, 60
n_positives_img, n_negatives_img = 17874, 26308 
n_total_img = 44182

#Imports of datasets inside Drive
ds_negatives = np.loadtxt('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/negative_depth.txt')
ds_positives = np.loadtxt('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/positive_depth.txt')


#Labeled arrays for datasets
arrayceros = np.zeros(n_negatives_img)
arrayunos = np.ones(n_positives_img)

#Reshaping of datasets to convert separate them
arraynegativos= ds_negatives.reshape(( n_negatives_img, img_width, img_height))
arraypositivos= ds_positives.reshape((n_positives_img, img_width, img_height))

#Labeling datasets with the arrays
ds_negatives_target = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((arraynegativos, arrayceros))
ds_positives_target = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((arraypositivos, arrayunos))

#Concatenate 2 datasets and shuffle them
ds_concatenate = ds_negatives_target.concatenate(ds_positives_target)
datasetfinal = ds_concatenate.shuffle(n_total_img)
```

But when I try to separate my dataset 80/20 to validate my CNN:

```
trainingdataset, validatedataset = train_test_split(datasetfinal, test_size=0.2, random_state=25)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Singleton array arrayshapes: ((80, 60), ()), types: (tf.float64, tf.float64)>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

Any ideas? Thank in advance!!!

Comment: And another solution is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50185329/2423278

Comment: @Kaveh AFAIK you can not split it by using `validation_split` because the total size is not known everytime.

Comment: @Frightera, Yes. You're right. I thought since it is a finite dataset, it should be supported, while it is not supported for TensorSliceDataset .And thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ugurcan the size is 44182 imgs

Comment: Better to shuffle and split data before creating `tensorflow dataset`. @JavierDecenaCastillo