# How do I extract some items from a tf.data.Dataset without starting from the first one?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I’m following the [**Intro to TensorFlow for Deep Learning**](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-tensorflow-for-deep-learning--ud187) course from Udacity. One of the lessons goes through a Google Colab Notebook that explains how to work with the Fashion MNIST dataset ([Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l03c01_classifying_images_of_clothing.ipynb) and [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l03c01_classifying_images_of_clothing.ipynb) links).

When showing images from the dataset, the code always extracts the first ones, using the **NumPy** method `take()`. I would like to know how to access different parts of the datasets, but I don’t have enough knowledge of Python to do it.

The first example is this one:

```py
# Take a single image, and remove the color dimension by reshaping
for image, label in test_dataset.take(1):
  break;

image = image.numpy().reshape((28,28))
```

What should I do to only take the second one?
If I just change the first parameter from 1 to 2, nothing changes, I guess because
I’m taking the first 2 elements, but still reading only the first one. Is there a way of taking only one item but skipping some of them?

By reading some answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213766/split-a-dataset-created-by-tensorflow-dataset-api-in-to-train-and-test) I have found out about the `skip()` method, but it looks like it takes all elements until the end, but I only want to extract a few items, in this case only one.

The second example is this one:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(train_dataset.take(25)):
    image = image.numpy().reshape((28,28))
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[label])
plt.show()
```

This one takes the first 25 items: how can I start reading images from let’s say the 100th?

In the third and last example they do a very similar thing:

```
for test_images, test_labels in test_dataset.take(1):
  test_images = test_images.numpy()
  test_labels = test_labels.numpy()
  predictions = model.predict(test_images)
```

How do I start from the second or third batch of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for getting items after 100th, You can do this:

1. Set `batch_size = 100`
2. Use this line : `dataset = dataset.skip(1).take(1)`. With this line you skip first 100 element and start from 101 to 200 `(because batch_size == 100)`.

Example Code:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


dataset = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', as_supervised=True, split = 'train').batch(100)
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
for iter, (image, label) in enumerate(dataset.skip(1).take(2)):
    print(f"{1*(iter+1)}01 -> {1*(iter+1)}10 images")
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,5,figsize=(15,6))
    for idx, axe in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
        axe.axis('off')
        axe.imshow(image[idx][...,0])
        axe.set_title(class_names[label[idx]])
    plt.show()
    print()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, so basically what I was missing was the possibility to combine `skip` and `take` together, so whatever range I want, I will just need to specify the offset with `skip` and the amount of items with `take`. I have tested in all the three cases listed and it works, even without changing the `batch_size`. Thanks!

Comment: @GiorgioTempesta, Welcome, But consider and careful about this, when you call `take(2)` for example, you get `2*batch_size` from items. if for example, you change `batch(1)` you get an error because you don't have 10 items for showing.