# Splitting a data set for CNN

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Suppose, I have a tensor `tfDataSet` as follows:

```
data3d = [
[[7.042   9.118  0.      1.    1.    1.    1.    1.    0.    0.   1.   ]
 [5.781   5.488  7.47    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.399   5.166  6.452   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.373   4.852  6.069   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.423   5.164  6.197   0.    0.    0.    0.    2.    1.    0.   0.   ]]
,
[[ 5.247  4.943  6.434   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [ 5.485  8.103  8.264   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.   1.   ]
 [ 6.675  9.152  9.047   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.   1.   ]
 [ 6.372  8.536 11.954   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.   1.   ]
 [ 5.669  5.433  6.703   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.   0.   ]]
, 
[[5.304   4.924  6.407   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.461   5.007  6.088   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.265   5.057  6.41    0.    0.    0.    0.    3.    0.    0.   1.   ]
 [5.379   5.026  6.206   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.525   5.154  6.      0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]]
,
[[5.403   5.173  6.102   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.588   5.279  6.195   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.381   5.238  6.675   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.   1.   ]
 [5.298   5.287  6.668   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]
 [5.704   7.411  4.926   0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    1.    0.   0.   ]]
,

... ... ... ...
... ... ... ...
]

tfDataSet = tf.convert_to_tensor(data3d)
```

In each 2D arry inside the tensor,  1st eight columns are features, and the rest three columns are one-hot-encoded labels.

Suppose, I want to feed this tensor into a CNN. For that, I need to do two things:

- (1) split the `data3d` into `trainData3d`, `validData3d`, and `testData3d`
- (2) split each of the above three into `featureData3d` and `labelData3d`.

Now, my question is, which one of the above steps should I do first and which one should I do second in order for being least expensive?

Explain why.

If I do #2 first, how can the feature and labels data maintain their correspondence?

Cross-posted: [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/448402/splitting-a-data-set-for-cnn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do #1 -> #2. The advantage would be that, even if you want to shuffle your `trainData3d`, it would be ensured that the right data and labels still belong together. Otherwise you need to ensure that `data` and `label` are shuffled in the same order. I think in TF  this is not trivial, as you'd need to shuffle a batch of indices and then use `tf.gather`, which is kind of slow.
As for the efficiency, I think the order doesn't matter much. Either way you'd need 6 operations and this would all be slicing operations. With shuffling, I think #1 -> #2 is still better, as you only need to shuffle once, but this also should not matter much.

If `data3d` is a [TensorFlow Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), you could use `shuffle`, `take` and `skip` to slice your data like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51258695/15019223).

Or you could do #2 and then use the [train-test-split from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to split into train and test set. This would transform your data back to numpy arrays though.

Comment: `sklearn` or `pandas` are not options.

Comment: Then I'd go the `Dataset` route in the link. Or is it not applicable to your case?